# Load an object from an XML with a namespace

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have looked around and have not been able to implement a solutions for what I need. I apologize if this seems like a repeat questions.

I'm querying an IDOL service and need to load an object with from the xml response.

Give the sample xml:

```
<autnresponse xslns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
  <action>QUERY</action>
  <response>SUCCESS</response>
  <responsedata>
    <autn:numhits>2</autn:numhits>
    <autn:totalhits>2</autn:totalhits>
    <autn:totaldbdocs>2</autn:totaldbdocs>
    <autn:totaldbsecs>2</autn:totaldbsecs>
    <autn:hit>
      <autn:reference>http://blah</autn:reference>
      <autn:title>my title</autn:title>
    </autn:hit>
    <autn:hit>
      <autn:reference>http://blah</autn:reference>
      <autn:title>my title</autn:title>
    </autn:hit>        
  </responsedata>
</autnresponse>
```

I'm trying to load a list of a custom object with linq to XML.

Here is what I have tried as code, and I'm always getting no results.

```
 var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
 namespaceManager.AddNamespace("autn", "http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/");
```

... Load Xelemet.....

```
IEnumerable<XElement> urls = raw.Elements(IDOLModule.GetNamespace()+ "hit");
            foreach (var single in urls)
            {
                var t = new url();
                t.Title="";
                t.Url="";
                listURL.Add(t);
            }
```

The **urls** variable is always coming back empty. I just need to target the autn:hits nodes and load their data to the object.

Cheers,

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid. It does not define the autn namespace.

Comment: I stripped out the namespace when I was re-formatting the true values. that was my mistake. The namespace is present inthe 'real' output. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You could try something like that:***

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<autnresponse xmlns:autn=""http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/"">
                                  <action>QUERY</action>
                                  <response>SUCCESS</response>
                                  <responsedata>
                                    <autn:numhits>2</autn:numhits>
                                    <autn:totalhits>2</autn:totalhits>
                                    <autn:totaldbdocs>2</autn:totaldbdocs>
                                    <autn:totaldbsecs>2</autn:totaldbsecs>
                                    <autn:hit>
                                      <autn:reference>http://blah</autn:reference>
                                      <autn:title>my title</autn:title>
                                    </autn:hit>
                                    <autn:hit>
                                      <autn:reference>http://blah</autn:reference>
                                      <autn:title>my title</autn:title>
                                    </autn:hit>
                                  </responsedata>
                                </autnresponse>");
XNamespace ns = ("http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/");
//Console.WriteLine(doc.Descendants(ns + "numhits").First().Value);
IEnumerable<XElement> hits=doc.Descendants(ns + "hit");
foreach (XElement h in hits){
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}",h.Name.ToString(),h.Elements().First().Value));
};
```

Comment: This worked. I'm not sure how I miss just using the XNamespace. Cheers,